# Xamarin.forms - How do I create draggable elements (Markers) on a MapView?

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and come from Android and Swift dev.  I'm just curious as to what would be a good approach or direction to start in when investigating on how to do this?  It appears with the Xamarin.Form.Map, it only allows me to use pins.

But on Android Google Maps API I have MarkerDrag listener interfaces and in Swift I can make markers draggable.  How do I go about setting up Map Listeners for the Xamarin.Forms Map views?  Please, nothing too detailed, just an idea of where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

-T

Answer (score 2):

> But on Android Google Maps API I have MarkerDrag listener interfaces and in Swift I can make markers draggable. How do I go about setting up Map Listeners for the Xamarin.Forms Map views? Please, nothing too detailed, just an idea of where to start.

For `Xamarin.Forms` if you want to access certain native feature that `Xamarin.Forms` doesn't possess, you need [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction). Also for maps:

1. Create a custom empty control for map in PCL:

   ```
   public class CustomMap:Map
   {}
   ```
2. Consume it in your xaml page:

   ```
   <StackLayout>
       <local:CustomMap WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200"
           x:Name="MyMap"
           IsShowingUser="true"
           MapType="Hybrid" />
   </StackLayout>
   ```
3. Create a custom Renderer for it(below is just an example for how to set `MarkerDrag` event in Android.):

   ```
   [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MapsDemo.CustomMap),
       typeof(MarkerClusterRenderer))]
   namespace MapsDemo.Droid
   {
       public class MarkerClusterRenderer:MapRenderer,IOnMapReadyCallback
       {
           public MarkerClusterRenderer(Context c) : base(c)
           {

           }

           protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
           {
               base.OnMapReady(map);
               var markerOptions = new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MarkerOptions();
               markerOptions.SetTitle("Winffeeeeeeeeeee");
               markerOptions.SetPosition(new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.LatLng(37.051060, -122.014684));
               markerOptions.Draggable(true);
               map.AddMarker(markerOptions);

               map.MarkerDrag += Map_MarkerDrag;
           }

           private void Map_MarkerDrag(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerDragEventArgs e)
           {
               //implement your marker drag event here
           }

           protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
           {
               base.OnElementChanged(e);

               Control.GetMapAsync(this);
           }

       }
   }
   ```